# Finding recurrence for proving matrix rows sums is Fibonacci sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

I have a matrix with the values below

\begin{matrix}
  1 \\
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 10 & 6 & 4 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 15 & 10 & 10 & 4 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 21 & 15 & 20 & 10 & 5 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 9 & 8 & 28 & 21 & 35 & 20 & 15 & 5 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 10 & 9 & 36 & 28 & 56 & 35 & 35 & 15 & 6 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 11 & 10 & 45 & 36 & 84 & 56 & 70 & 35 & 21 & 6 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 12 & 11 & 55 & 45 & 120 & 84 & 126 & 70 & 56 & 21 & 7 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 13 & 12 & 66 & 55 & 165 & 120 & 210 & 126 & 126 & 56 & 28 & 7 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 14 & 13 & 78 & 66 & 220 & 165 & 330 & 210 & 252 & 126 & 84 & 28 & 8 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 15 & 14 & 91 & 78 & 286 & 220 & 495 & 330 & 462 & 252 & 210 & 84 & 36 & 8 & 1
\end{matrix}

I need to proove that the sum $F_n= F_{n,1} + F_{n,2} + \cdots + F_{n,n}$ is the n-th Fibonacci number.

Does anyone can help me? I need as simply as possible steps.

Thank you!

Comment: Try writing the matrix in a compact form first...

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat this numbers derived from the identity x^n = $\sum_{k=1}^{n} F_{n,k} \, x^{\left(1+ \left\lceil \frac{k-1}{2} \right\rceil\right)} (x-1) ^{\left\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2}\right\rfloor}$

Comment: Oh then I think you put that down. It's a lot easier to work with that form that the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

So if you can show that the patterns $F_{n+1,2r}=F_{n,2r-1}+F_{n,2r}$ and $F_{n+1, 2r+1}=F_{n,2r}=F_{n-1,2r-1}+F_{n-1,2r}$ persist - which may require a little consideration of the boundaries, you should be able to show that the even terms sum to the total of the row above and the odd terms sum to the total two rows above, and thereby show that the row sums satisfy the Fibonacci recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: See the following image:

[image]

In this image, rectangles with the same color have the same sum. I did this for the last row in your matrix but you can easily notice that this is valid for all rows. Then you can generalize.